# TYPO3 v7.6 TCEFORM.sys_file_metadata

Tags: typo3, typo3-7.x

Namely in TYPO3 v7.6 I have defined the meta-description as a required field.

PageTS:

```
TCEFORM.sys_file_metadata.title.config.eval = required
```

Now I would like to insert a little note under this heading. How do I do that? Is that possible? Find nothing in the TYPO3 documentary.

Comment: Is it not a # ?

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: I mean a hashtag at start of line? usually in typoscript it is a hashtag? But I guess you  maybe tried it already..